# CSS overflow-y: scroll scrollbar position not in the right place

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a smooth scroll in CSS from one page to the next. Everything seems to work well until I used `overflow-y: scroll;` then the scrollbar appears in the middle of the page width instead of the standard (sticking to the left).

[image: screengrab]

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  line-height: 1.6;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section id="sec1">Section 1</section>

    <section id="sec2">Section 2</section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code works well here. Perhaps the problem is in another part of the code. Insert more code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `<body>` has some default value for `margin` (for some browsers like Chrome) set it to zero. And to make the body occupy the complete width of the screen, set the `width` as `100%` or `100vw`.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%; // 100vw also works
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section id="sec1">Section 1</section>

    <section id="sec2">Section 2</section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider marking it as correct so it can help other people checking this question also! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try giving

```
 body {
   width: 100vw;
}
```

The `.container` width is set to `100%`, but it's parent does not have any width specified. That must be the issue. If it doesn't fix it, try also giving

```
html {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you gave it 'overflov-y:scroll' to container. it turns out there because its width is that much. try to change